How to approach the Multiple Stock Size 1D Cutting Stock problem?
First, I should note, I'm completely new to Linear Programming and haven't touched math more complex than basic algebra in a decade, so please forgive any lack of understanding here.
I'm looking to make an implementation of a solution to the 1D Cutting Stock Problem with multiple size stocks available. From what I understand, LP approaches are currently considered the most optimal solutions, but I have no idea how to go about actually structuring my code.
After a bit of looking around, I think Sonnet (a .NET wrapper for CLP, Coin-Or Linear Programming) should be sufficient for my Solver, and I think I'll be capable of translating a pseudocode algorithm to the correct code to use it, but as I don't have a solid example of a full solution to the problem as described I can't really figure out what I need to do to get this rolling.
I'm hoping someone on here can provide a pseudocode (language-agnostic) solution to this with some explanations of what's actually happening, from initial pattern generation to getting the optimized cutlist from the solver, if that's not too much to ask. I could also probably roll with an algorithm written in one of {Java, Python, VB.NET, C#.NET} if those are easier for whoever answers to write in.
To formally define the problem:

Given a set of stock lengths of unlimited quantity and a finite set of requested cut lengths, generate the optimal set of cut patterns to minimize waste.
(A bonus would be to optimize in such a way that the number of patterns used is minimized while still weighing waste as a constraint, so that "bundles" of stock could be cut at the same time.)

So, for instance:
Stock sizes available: {240, 288}
Cuts needed (quantity, length): {(6, 16), (7, 48), (4, 73.5)}

Output (stock length, qty, [cuts]):
- (240, 1, [73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 16])
- (240, 1, [73.5, 48, 48, 16, 16])
- (288, 1, [48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 16, 16, 16])


Welcome to ORSE. What you have is actually an integer linear program (ILP), because the variables are discrete. You cannot cut fractions of a length 48 piece from different pieces of stock and glue them together to make the length 48 item. So CLP is not an appropriate solver. Cbc (another COIN-OR project) would be, as would a variety of other open-source and commercial solvers.

Appreciate the explanation on the distinction. I believe Sonnet encapsulates CDC as well, but if not I'll make sure to grab its library as well. Thanks!

In case you're not looking to make the implementation but for an already working one https://github.com/fontanf/packingsolver

@fontanf, thanks for the example, I hadn't come across that one in my Github digging for some reason. I will say I'm also under a language constraint, and am also hoping to use some memory overhead to pass along other objects with each cut/pattern to track related information to each piece. I'll read through yours tonight, though I'll admit I'm not very well versed in C and C++, so it might take me some thinking. Is that available as a callable library, or is it a standalone solver for bin packing type problems?

@Adam The package can be used both as a standalone solver and a C++ callback library.

Here is SAS code to implement @prubin's third suggested approach ("price and branch" heuristic).  It finds lower bound $48175$ and upper bound $48192$ in a few seconds.
data RawMaterialData;
   input rawLength;
   datalines;
 60
120
240
288
;

data DemandData;
   input demandQuantity demandLength;
   datalines;
 50 66
100 64
200 63.5
200 57.5
100 37.375
100 36.375
200 21.5
200  7
200  6
;

proc optmodel printlevel=0;
   /* declare parameters and sets */
   set RAWS;
   num rawLength {RAWS};
   set ITEMS;
   num demandQuantity {ITEMS};
   num demandLength {ITEMS};
   num numPatterns init card(ITEMS);
   set PATTERNS = 1..numPatterns;
   num patternLength {PATTERNS};
   /* a[i,j] = number of times that item i appears in pattern j */
   num a {ITEMS, PATTERNS};
   /* pi[i] = dual variable for SatisfyDemand[i] constraint */
   num pi {ITEMS} init 0;
   num epsilon = 1E-6;

   /* read input data */
   read data RawMaterialData into RAWS=[_N_] rawLength;
   read data DemandData into ITEMS=[_N_] demandQuantity demandLength;

   /* generate trivial initial columns using largest raw */
   num max_rawLength = max {r in RAWS} rawLength[r];
   for {j in PATTERNS} patternLength[j] = max_rawLength;
   for {i in ITEMS, j in PATTERNS} a[i,j] = (if (i = j) then floor(max_rawLength/demandLength[i]) else 0);

   /* define master problem */
   /* X[j] = number of times that pattern j is used */
   var X {PATTERNS} >= 0 integer;
   minimize TotalLengthUsed = sum {j in PATTERNS} patternLength[j] * X[j];
   con SatisfyDemand {i in ITEMS}:
      sum {j in PATTERNS} a[i,j] * X[j] >= demandQuantity[i];
   problem Master include X TotalLengthUsed SatisfyDemand;

   /* define column generation subproblem */
   /* Y[i] = number of times that item i appears in pattern */
   var Y {ITEMS} >= 0 integer;
   var IsRaw {RAWS} binary;
   minimize ReducedCost = 
      sum {r in RAWS} rawLength[r] * IsRaw[r] - sum {i in ITEMS} pi[i] * Y[i];
   con OneRaw:
      sum {r in RAWS} IsRaw[r] = 1;
   con RawLengthCon:
      sum {i in ITEMS} demandLength[i] * Y[i] <= sum {r in RAWS} rawLength[r] * IsRaw[r];
   problem Subproblem include Y IsRaw ReducedCost OneRaw RawLengthCon;

   /* main loop */
   do while (1);
      /* master problem */
      use problem Master;
      put "Solving master problem...";
      solve with lp relaxint / solver=ps basis=warmstart logfreq=1;
      for {i in ITEMS} pi[i] = SatisfyDemand[i].dual;

      /* subproblem */
      use problem Subproblem;
      put "Solving column generation subproblem...";
      solve with milp / logfreq=0;
      for {i in ITEMS} Y[i] = round(Y[i]);

      if ReducedCost >= -epsilon then leave;

      /* include new pattern */
      numPatterns = numPatterns + 1;
      for {r in RAWS: IsRaw[r].sol > 0.5} do;
         patternLength[numPatterns] = rawLength[r];
         leave;
      end;
      for {i in ITEMS} a[i,numPatterns] = Y[i];
   end;

   /* solve IP, using rounded-up LP solution as warm start */
   use problem Master;
   for {j in PATTERNS} X[j] = ceil(X[j].sol);
   put "Solving (restricted) master problem as IP...";
   solve with milp / primalin;

   /* cleanup solution and save to output data set */
   for {j in PATTERNS} X[j] = round(X[j].sol);
   create data solution(drop=pattern) from [pattern]={j in PATTERNS: X[j].sol > 0}
      number=X patternLength
      {i in ITEMS} <col('numItems'||i)=a[i,j]>;
quit;


Does SAS provide licenses for academia?

@Kuifje Yes: https://www.sas.com/en_us/learn/academic-programs/software.html

This is not a direct answer to your problem, but more about possibly focusing your question. There are multiple ways to handle a 1D cutting stock problem using an integer linear program. Apologies for the length of what follows.
The first and simplest (most primitive) approach is to set an a priori limit on how many pieces of each size stock are available and then use integer variables $x_{ijk}$ (how many output pieces of type $i$ are cut from the $j$-th unit of stock size $k$) and binary variables $y_{jk}$ (did I use the $j$-th unit of stock size $k$). This is unwieldy for "large" problem instances (where the definition of "large" is continually changing as algorithms get smarter and computers get faster), but works fine on your test problem. CPLEX solved your problem instance in under a second.
The second approach, which I don't think is used that often, is to calculate in advance every possible pattern for each stock size and then use integer variables $x_p$ (how many stock pieces were cut with pattern $p$). The issue with this approach is that the number of possible patterns quickly gets out of control.
The third approach uses a master problem like the second approach, but with a limited set of possible patterns, plus a subproblem (knapsack type linear program) that generates new patterns on the fly. The master problem is initially relaxed to a linear program (dropping the requirement that the cut variables be integers but keeping everything else), you go back and forth between the relaxed master and the subproblem (using information from the most recent solution of the relaxed master to find new patterns in the subproblem, then adding those patterns to the master), and eventually the subproblem stops finding new patterns. At that point, you return the master variables to integer and solve the master as an integer program. The catch with this approach is that it is a heuristic: you are not guaranteed to get the true optimal solution.
The fourth approach is similar to the third in that patterns are generated on the fly, but it uses an advanced solution method known as "branch-and-price" or "branch, price and cut". The good news is that, given enough time and memory, it is guaranteed to find the optimal solution. The bad news is that it's somewhat cutting edge (pun intended), and not all solvers incorporate it.
So you might want to clarify whether your interest in this is just educational, or whether you are looking to solve actual "real world" instances. If the latter, it would help to have a sense of how large they might be.

For the OP's benefit, the fourth approach is what the SAS code in my answer provides under the hood.

Thanks for the in-depth explanation, and thanks RP for relating one to code. My interest is in solving for a real-world problem, trying to integrate automatic CutList generation into some in-house software I inherited. Currently, it's done by hand, but usually at the scale of the example above: a handful of different stock lengths available, and maybe 25 required lengths or so at a time. A recent project, though, had a much larger scale, in the realm of 5+ stock lengths and up to hundreds each of a good few required lengths, and made me realize I never wanted to do it by hand again.

I'd be interested in the "cutting edge" 4th solution if I wasn't worried about the "time and memory" comment, as I don't want to require hardware too hefty. The first approach sounds like my problem but with stock limits, which I'm assuming I could fake "unlimited" stock using a sufficiently high number for the number of pieces of stock available (ex, above I need 7 output, so set my stock limits at 7x 240 and 7x 288). The third approach also sounds promising, as a perfect solution is not entirely necessary, and would likely be more optimal and definitely faster than by hand.

@Adam Are you able to share data for the larger instances?

Let's see if I can make this clean enough to be understood... Here's a single stock type's initial state from a larger-but-not-that-large project: Available Stock: {60, 120, 240, 288} Required output (count, length): {(50, 66), (100, 64), (200, 63.5), (200, 57.5), (100, 37.375), (100, 36.375), (200, 21.5), (200, 7), (200, 6)}. Of note, this project had 11 different stock types used, all with similar size required output.

The total combined length of all the required output in your example is 48,175. CPLEX got a solution with a combined length of 48,492, guaranteed to be within 0.65% of optimal, in five minutes on my not particularly stellar PC. That's using the first approach I listed.

There is a solution with value 48,180

@fontaf Thanks for this correction.  I should not have ignored the log warning that Ryan-Foster branching might not be valid here.  I'll update the code in my answer.

For the third approach, the LP lower bound turns out to be $48175$, which immediately implies a better lower bound of $12\lceil 48175/12\rceil=48180$ because the four allowed raw lengths have gcd $12$.

It turns out that for the data in the comment above, the second approach works fine. There are 161,520 valid cutting patterns. It only takes a second or so to generate all of them, and CPLEX can solve the resulting IP model to optimality in a little over 20 seconds. The virtue of this approach, to me, is that the IP model is extremely straightforward, so it could be used with any solver.

Here is SAS code to solve the problem:
data RawMaterialData;
   input rawLength;
   datalines;
240
288
; 

data DemandData;
   input demandQuantity demandLength;
   datalines;
6 16
7 48
4 73.5
;

proc optmodel;
   /* declare input parameters and read data */
   set RAW_LENGTHS;
   read data RawMaterialData into RAW_LENGTHS=[rawLength];

   set DEMAND_LENGTHS;
   num demandQuantity {DEMAND_LENGTHS};
   read data DemandData into DEMAND_LENGTHS=[demandLength] demandQuantity;

   num minrawLength = min {c in RAW_LENGTHS} c;
   num maxrawLength = max {c in RAW_LENGTHS} c;
   num numRaws = sum {d in DEMAND_LENGTHS: minrawLength >= d} ceil(demandQuantity[d]/floor(minrawLength/d));
   set RAWS = 1..numRaws;
   put numRaws=;

   /* declare decision variables */
   /* UseRaw[r] = 1 if raw r is used; 0 otherwise */
   var UseRaw {RAWS} binary;

   /* IsRawLength[r,c] = 1 if raw r has length c; 0 otherwise */
   var IsRawLength {RAWS, RAW_LENGTHS} binary;

   /* RawLength[r] = length of raw r */
   var RawLength {RAWS} >= 0 <= maxrawLength;

   /* NumAssign[d,r] = number of units of demand length d assigned to raw r */
   var NumAssign {d in DEMAND_LENGTHS, RAWS} >= 0 <= min(demandQuantity[d], maxrawLength/d) integer;

   /* declare objective */
   minimize TotalLengthUsed = sum {r in RAWS} RawLength[r];

   /* declare constraints */
   con DemandCon {d in DEMAND_LENGTHS}:
      sum {r in RAWS} NumAssign[d,r] >= demandQuantity[d];

   con OneLengthPerRaw {r in RAWS}:
      sum {c in RAW_LENGTHS} IsRawLength[r,c] = UseRaw[r]
   suffixes=(block=r);

   con RawLengthCon {r in RAWS}:
      sum {c in RAW_LENGTHS} c * IsRawLength[r,c] = RawLength[r]
   suffixes=(block=r);

   con KnapsackCon {r in RAWS}:
      sum {d in DEMAND_LENGTHS} d * NumAssign[d,r] <= RawLength[r]
   suffixes=(block=r);

   /* call mixed integer linear programming solver,
      using automated Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition algorithm */
   solve with milp / decomp;

   /* renumber used raws consecutively starting from 1 */
   num rawId init 1;
   num rawMap {RAWS};
   num assignedRawLength {RAWS} init .;
   num numAssigned {DEMAND_LENGTHS, RAWS} init .;
   for {r in RAWS: UseRaw[r].sol > 0.5} do;
      rawMap[r] = rawId;
      rawId     = rawId + 1;
      for {c in RAW_LENGTHS: IsRawLength[r,c].sol > 0.5} do;
         assignedRawLength[rawMap[r]] = c;
         leave;
      end;
      for {d in DEMAND_LENGTHS: NumAssign[d,r].sol > 0.5}
         numAssigned[d,rawMap[r]] = NumAssign[d,r];
   end;

   /* create output data sets */
   create data AssignedRawLengths from 
      [raw]={r in RAWS: assignedRawLength[r] > 0.5} assignedRawLength;
   create data AssignedCuts from 
      [demandLength raw]={d in DEMAND_LENGTHS, r in RAWS: numAssigned[d,r] > 0.5} numAssigned;
quit;


Hi, thanks for the response. I'm not sure I understand it completely, though, as I'm not familiar with SAS. I ran it through a couple of conversion tools to get it into a slightly more readable format, but there's some things that don't seem to have translated well enough for me to understand.
For example, your decision variables all converted to Dictionary objects, but Sonnet only has two variable types, Integer and Continuous. I think once I have those figured out I should be able to get the constraints in place, and then I guess it's just a matter of telling Sonnet to solve the model?

The VAR statements in my answer declare families of binary, binary, continuous, and integer variables, respectively.  As an alternative to binary, you can equivalently specify as integer with lower bound 0 and upper bound 1.

Thanks for the clarification, and I'm just now noticing it looks like some additional comments were added in. I'll make an attempt at getting that set up with your example code translated to what I need it in, and see how that goes, however it may be tomorrow morning before I get around to it as our work day is winding down here. I should be able to convert anything affected by the binary to integer switch, so I'm hoping this gets me going somewhere. I'm definitely interested to see what the resource usage and time to solve look like with this "4th approach" per prubin's examples.

Could I get a little clarification around what minimize TotalLengthUsed = sum {r in RAWS} RawLength[r]; is doing? I get that it's attempting to minimize the total length of stock used, and am guessing the first half of the right side is doing something with the sum of all lengths in RAWS, but what's the reason or function of the RawLength[r] portion doing, and how does it interact with the sum function right there beside it?

minimize declares an objective to be minimized.  TotalLengthUsed is the name of the objective function.  RawLength is a family of bounded continuous decision variables, declared in a previous var statement.  sum {r in RAWS} RawLength[r] is the summation formula for the objective function; as you said, it is the total length of all raws used.  Mathematically, it is like $\text{minimize } z = \sum_{r\in R} x_r$.
